# Convert String[] to comma separated string in java

Tags: java

i have one `String[]`

```
String[] name = {"amit", "rahul", "surya"};
```

i want to send name as parameter in sql query inside IN clause
so how do i convert into a format

```
'amit','rahul','surya'
```

Comment: What about `String[] name = {"O'Neill"};`

Comment: please change the accepted answer to the top voted one

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
if (name.length > 0) {
    StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String n : name) {
        nameBuilder.append("'").append(n.replace("'", "\\'")).append("',");
        // can also do the following
        // nameBuilder.append("'").append(n.replace("'", "''")).append("',");
    }

    nameBuilder.deleteCharAt(nameBuilder.length() - 1);

    return nameBuilder.toString();
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Then I would have written a bunch of checks. I'm just explaining the concept, not giving the save-all example.

Comment: Again, concepts... And thanks for the down-vote. But there you go, fixed it.

Comment: thanks buddy you save my day but if you don't mind can you also give the answer  of @Bart Kiers because i might get that situation and i am new to programming plz

Comment: Nico, if it was just concepts, you should have mentioned that, or have posted pseudo code instead. However, you posted code that was valid Java. Now that you have fixed your answer, I removed the down-vote (which I always do if an answer gets improved). No need to get all cranky about a down-vote: I down-vote the answer you provide, not you as a person.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - Not grumpy at all. That's why I fixed it :) Otherwise I really would not have bothered. But yes, I get your point about valid Java code, that's my bad. And so we learn.

Comment: Strings aren't mutable. Your `replaceAll` call does nothing. Even if you did set name to the new string, it still wouldn't do anything, seeing as `\'` is the escape sequence for `'`.

Comment: @Obicere - Wow don't know how I missed that... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ohhh, why there's need to write so many source lines if you can simply use `String.join(...)` or `TextUtils.join(...)`?

Comment: @EugeneBrusov I'm going to go and guess because the answer posted in 2011 long before the release of Java 8 ;)

Answer (score 246):

Either write a simple method yourself, or use one of the various utilities out there.

Personally I use apache StringUtils ([StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Iterator,%20char%29))

edit: in Java 8, you don't need this at all anymore:

```
String joined = String.join(",", name);
```

Comment: Exactly! You can even define your own delimiters : `StringUtils.join(names,',');`

Comment: `String list = "'" + StringUtils.join(names,"','") + "'";` this would give you the Single quotes needed by the SQL request.

Comment: For android : `TextUtils.join(",", stringArrayOfEmails)`

Answer (score 89):

Android developers are probably looking for TextUtils.join

Android docs:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

Code:

```
String[] name = {"amit", "rahul", "surya"};
TextUtils.join(",",name)
```

Answer (score 67):

Nice and simple: but java8 required!

```java
String result = String.join(",", names);
```

Answer (score 47):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String n : name) { 
    if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(',');
    sb.append("'").append(n).append("'");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: @Bmoeller Have you tried `TextUtils.join(...)`? I guess one line code is even better and simpler than five ones.

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` API to form a comma separated result from string array in Java.

`StringUtils.join(strArr,",");`

Answer (score 9):

If you already have Spring Framework as a dependency, you could also use the very simple util method:

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(String[] array)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also simplify it using the Guava library:

```
String[] name = {"amit", "rahul", "surya"};
String str = "'" + Joiner.on(",").skipNulls().join(name)
    .replace(",", "','") + "'";
```

Comment: How do I use Guava library where output is: `"amit,rahul,surya"`?

Answer (score 6):

Extention for prior Java 8 solution

```
String result = String.join(",", name);
```

If you need prefix or/ and suffix for array values

```
 StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
 for (CharSequence cs: name) {
     joiner.add("'" + cs + "'");
 }
 return joiner.toString();
```

Or simple method concept

```
  public static String genInValues(String delimiter, String prefix, String suffix, String[] name) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    for (CharSequence cs: name) {
      joiner.add(prefix + cs + suffix);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
  }
```

For example

```
For Oracle i need "id in (1,2,3,4,5)" 
then use genInValues(",", "", "", name);
```

```
But for Postgres i need "id in (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))"
then use genInValues(",", "(", ")", name);
```

Answer (score 5):

use `StringBuilder` and iterate over your String[], and append each String into it:

```
public static String convert(String[] name) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String st : name) { 
        sb.append('\'').append(st).append('\'').append(',');
    }
    if (name.length != 0) sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with one line of code:

```
Arrays.toString(strings).replaceAll("[\\[.\\].\\s+]", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] name = {"amit", "rahul", "surya"};


public static String arrayToString(String array[])
{
    if (array.length == 0) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        sb.append(",'").append(array[i]).append("'");
    }
    return sb.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `substring(1)`, but what if `array.length == 0`?

Answer (score 2):

i use this

```
public static String convertToCommaSeparated(String[] strings) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    for (int i = 0; strings != null && i < strings.length; i++) {
        sb.append(strings[i]);
        if (i < strings.length - 1) {
            sb.append(',');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java 8 for none string array and none primitive object (Long, Integer, ...)

```
List<Long> ids = Arrays.asList(1l, 2l,3l);
ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))))
```

In java 8 for specific field of an objets array (example a car with 2 fields color and speed)

```
List<Car> cars= Cars.asList(car1, cars2,car3);
    cars.stream().map(Car::getColor).collect(Collectors.joining(","))))
```

Combine `map` with `valueOf` for none String field of an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

USE `StringUtils.join` function:
E.g.

```
String myCsvString = StringUtils.join(myList, ",")
```

Comment: Why post an answer that has been previously posted multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] paramIdIdList={"P001","P002","P003"};

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(String paramId : paramIdIdList) {
                builder.append(paramId+",");
            }
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() -1);
            String paramIds = builder.toString();
System.Out.Println(paramIds );
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code is exactly doing.

Comment: Converting String[] to comma separated string

Comment: In your answer, because right knows there is some code. Nothing more and nothing less, but its no help.

Answer (score 1):

As tempting and "cool" as the code may appear, **do not use `fold` or `reduce`** on large collections of strings, as these will suffer from the [string concatenation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/314291)

```
String[] strings = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
Optional<String> result = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .reduce((a, b) -> String.format("%s,%s", a, b));
System.out.println(result.get());
```

Instead, as per other answers, use `String.join()` if you already have a collection, or a `StringBuilder` if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
String newNameList=null;

 for(int i = name.length;i>=0;i--){
    if(newNameList==null){
        newNameList = "\'" + name[name.length - i] + "\'";
    }
    else{
        newNameList += ",\'" + name[name.length - i] + "\'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want not to spawn StringBuilder for such simple operation. Please note that I've changed name of your array from *name* to *names* for sake of content conformity:

```
String[] names = {"amit", "rahul", "surya"};

String namesString = "";
int delimeters = (names.size() - 1);
for (String name : names)
    namesString += (delimeters-- > 0) ? "'" + name + "'," : "'" + name + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Two lines (excluding declarations; 'finalstring' should be initially declared equal to an empty string), if you don't care a lot about vertically spacing the for() loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<string_array.length; i++) {finalstring += string_array[i]+",";}
finalstring = finalstring.substring(0,finalstring.length()-1);
```

Two lines, you're done. :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a Utility method to split an array and put your custom delimiter, using

```
String.replace(String,String)
Arrays.toString(Object[])
```

here it is :

```
public static String toString(String delimiter, Object[]array){
    String s = "";

    // split array
    if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
        s = Arrays.toString(array).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    }

    // place delimiter (notice the space in ", ")
    if(delimiter != null){
        s = s.replace(", ", delimiter);
    }

    return s;
}
```

change the second argument type to suite your array type

Answer (score 0):

This would be an optimized way of doing it

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String n : arr) { 
    sb.append("'").append(n).append("',");
}
if(sb.length()>0)
    sb.setLength(sbDiscrep.length()-1);
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better rename `name` to `names` since its an Array.
Java 8+ solution, taking into :

```
String[] names = {"amit", "rahul", "surya","O'Neil"};
// For each name:
// single quote with another single quote
// & put single quotes around 
// & add comma at end 
String sql = Stream.<String>of(names)
    .reduce("", (acc,s)-> acc + "'" + s.replaceAll("'","''") + "',")
// Remove last trailing comma
sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length()-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

**This my be helpful!!!**

```
private static String convertArrayToString(String [] strArray) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i<= strArray.length-1; i++) {
                if(i == strArray.length-1) {
                    builder.append("'"+strArray[i]+"'");
                }else {
                    builder.append("'"+strArray[i]+"'"+",");
                }
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.