# How can I set a String[] parameter to a native query?

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, jpql

This is my PostgreSQL function:

```
salvarArquivoGeometricoCasoZeroPOINT
(dimensao text,tableName text,tuplas text[],srid text)
```

It has a `text[]` parameter, and I want to pass a Java `String[]` to it from my JPQL:

```
public String salvarGeometriaCaso0(String[] tuplas,FileDto arquivo){
        Query query =
        em().createNativeQuery("select 
salvarArquivoGeometricoCasoZeroPOINT(?1,?2,?3,?4)");
        query.setParameter(1,arquivo.getGeo());//String
        query.setParameter(2,arquivo.getTable());/String
        query.setParameter(3,tuplas);//String[]
        query.setParameter(4,arquivo.getSrid());//String
        return (String) query.getSingleResult();//function returns a Text, so cast to String
}
```

The above code fails with the exception:

```
ERROR] Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can not infer a SQL
type to use for an instance of [Ljava.lang.String;. 
Use setObject () with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

so I'm not sure how to call my function from EclipseLink.

Comment: Did you _try_ "[Using] `setObject ()` with an explicit `Types` value to specify the type to use?"

Comment: Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Instead of `query.setParameter(3, tuplas)` you'd call `setObject()` on a `PreparedStatement`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: But I'm using EclipseLink. I have to follow some patters, I can't use a PreparedStatement.

Comment: Which EclipseLink version? And which PgJDBC version? I thought EclipseLink and PgJDBC understood that `String[]` mapped to `text[]`.

Comment: @Craig Ringer : Yes, and I have a function returning a text[] and I catch the result casting the object to String[].                String[] result = (String[])query.getSingleResult;                   But setting String[] as a parameter returns that error. I'm using EclipseLink 3.2 and Postgres 9.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing by passing a Java array of type String[] to `PreparedStatement.setObject(...)` results in the behaviour you report. It appears that PgJDBC doesn't accept a Java array as an argument to `PreparedStatement.setObject()`, with or without a `Types.ARRAY` parameter.

### Compliance

The JDBC spec, *16.5 "Array Objects"*, suggests that the JDBC `Array` exists partly so the client doesn't have to copy big arrays into memory, they can be used by reference. I'm not too sure whether the JDBC driver is required to accept raw Java arrays as parameters. All the spec code refers to `java.sql.Array` and the spec makes it clear that arrays are mapped via the `Array` interface in Appendix B and elsewhere. In a quick search/reading I could find *no* mention of passing raw Java arrays other than `byte[]` as  parameters or returning them as results.

However, in §16.5.4 the JDBC4.2 draft spec reads:

```
A Java array may be passed as an input parameter by calling the method
PreparedSatement.setObject.
```

though all the rest of the code there refers to `Array` objects. Do they mean `Array` by "a Java array"? Or do they mean a raw native Java array like `String[]`?

It looks to me like clients are supposed to use the `java.sql.Array` interface via `Connection.createArrayOf(...)`, so EclipseLink is probably doing the wrong thing.

### What do do about it

Try updating EclipseLink to 2.4 in the hopes it uses [the commonly specified method of passing arrays to JDBC via a java.sql.Array object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

You may also need to annotate the mapping with [`@Array`](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_array.htm), an EclipseLink extension. See also [this forum thread re 2.3](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/245069/) and [bug 361701](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361701).

It appears you may have to implement your own type handler for EclipseLink to override its behaviour. To correctly set an array parameter via PgJDBC you must use:

```
    Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("text", strArray);
    pstmt.setArray(1, sqlArray);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

... where `conn` and `pstmt` are a `java.sql.Connection` and a `PreparedStatement` respectively, and `strArray` is a `String[]` instance.

See [Custom data types in the eclipselink wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Customizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_%28ELUG%29#Creating_Custom_Data_Types).

On a side note, the use of a string type name to specify the array's data type in `createArrayOf` seems kind of insane given the existence of `java.sql.Types`. It makes portability much harder; the above code won't run on (say) Oracle, because Oracle wants `VARCHAR` not `text` as a type name.

---

Note: The unit test `org/postgresql/test/jdbc2/ArrayTest.java` has `ArrayTest.testSetArray()`, which at line 166 tests:

```
    pstmt.setObject(1, arr);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

... however the type of `arr` is `java.sql.Array`, not `int[]`. It's a JDBC array type, not a regular Java array.

Comment: Update the eclipseLink didn't work. The only way was use the pure JDBC

Answer (score 7):

I am very late to answer it.

This solution is kind of workaround using postgreSQL built-in function, which definitely worked for me.

[reference blog](https://issue-and-solution.blogspot.de/2016/09/how-to-pass-string-to-postgresql-using.html)

**1) Convert String Array to  Comma Separated String**

If you are using Java8, it's pretty easy. other options are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622974/convert-string-to-comma-separated-string-in-java)

```
String commaSeparatedString = String.join(",",stringArray); // Java8 feature
```

**2) PostgreSQL built-in function string_to_array()**

you can find other postgreSQL array functions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html)

```
// tableName ( name text, string_array_column_name text[] )

String query = "insert into tableName(name,string_array_column_name ) values(?, string_to_array(?,',') )";


int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};

Object[] psParams = new Object[] {"Dhruvil Thaker",commaSeparatedString };

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, psParams ,types); // assuming you have jdbctemplate instance
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems EclipseLink doesn't fix the  [bug 361701.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361701) mentioned by @Craig Ringer.

The only way to pass a String[] as a parameter is using the JDBC without EclipseLink. Check the code.

```
Connection con = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
        Array tArray = con.createArrayOf("text", tuplas);
        PreparedStatement pstm =
        con.prepareStatement("select salvarArquivoGeometricoCasoZeroPOINT(?,?,?,?)");
        pstm.setString(1,arquivo.getGeoType());
        pstm.setString(2,arquivo.getTable());
        pstm.setArray(3,tArray);
        pstm.setString(4,arquivo.getSrid());
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

ConnectionHelper it's my java.sql.Connection class.

I appreciate the help of you guys: @Craig Ringer and @Matt Ball, Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you could also implement your own EclipseLink data type handler for arrays using the custom data type facilities. Dropping down to plain JDBC is probably easier though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when accidentally using `jdbcTemplate.update` instead of `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`