# Hibernate, Postgres & Array Type

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, hibernate

I'm stuck on a specific issue using **[array type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html)** in postgresql 9.3 mapped with hibernate 4.1.0. 
This type allows me to have really strong data model, without building lots of tables and joins.

In order to map a field stored with this particular type, I have used a [UserType](http://finethinking.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/hibernate-arrays-and-postgres/)

Anyway, it works well with pure hibernate (hql) but I need also to send **sql native query** to my database. When I do it, in spite of many tries, I have not found any way to do that.

I try many syntaxes based on this

```
String[] values = {"value1", "value2"};
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM instances WHERE values && :values";
Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString).addEntity(Instance.class);
query.setParameterList("values", values);
query.list();
```

I got
  Operator does not exists : text[] && character varying

It should give following syntax in jdbc : ['value1', 'value2'] and it seems to give 'value1'...

I tried many syntaxes
with

- Collection
- Pure Arrays
- [ :values ] syntax :  I got 
  Syntax error near "["

---

I need to send native query because I use [Materialized View](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) for performance gains.

My SQL Query works in postgresql console. So it is an hibernate specific issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mapping a postgres array with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I tried few versions based on Array Type introduced by JDBC4 : [How can I set a String[] parameter to a native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042181/how-can-i-set-a-string-parameter-to-a-native-query). Problem is also Hibernate (even in last version 4.3.1.final) does not work with this new features and gave me following error message

```
Could not determine a type for class: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
```

So I had to make a Specific UserType (based on several articles in stackoverflow, and others sources)

My Model

```
@Type(type = "fr.mycompany.dao.hibernate.types.ArrayUserType")
private String[] values;
```

My `ArrayUserType`

```
public class ArrayUserType implements UserType {

/** Constante contenant le type SQL "Array".
 */
protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

/**
 * Return the SQL type codes for the columns mapped by this type. The
 * codes are defined on <tt>java.sql.Types</tt>.
 * 
 * @return int[] the typecodes
 * @see java.sql.Types
 */
public final int[] sqlTypes() {
    return SQL_TYPES;
}

/**
 * The class returned by <tt>nullSafeGet()</tt>.
 * 
 * @return Class
 */
public final Class returnedClass() {
    return String[].class;
}

/**
 * Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a JDBC resultset. Implementors
 * should handle possibility of null values.
 * 
 * @param resultSet a JDBC result set.
 * @param names the column names.
 * @param session SQL en cours.
 * @param owner the containing entity 
 * @return Object
 * @throws org.hibernate.HibernateException exception levée par Hibernate
 * lors de la récupération des données.
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException exception SQL 
 * levées lors de la récupération des données.
 */
@Override
public final Object nullSafeGet(
        final ResultSet resultSet, 
        final String[] names, 
        final SessionImplementor session, 
        final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] array = (String[]) resultSet.getArray(names[0]).getArray();
    return array;
}

/**
 * Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement. Implementors
 * should handle possibility of null values. A multi-column type should be written
 * to parameters starting from <tt>index</tt>.
 * 
 * @param statement a JDBC prepared statement.
 * @param value the object to write
 * @param index statement parameter index
 * @param session sql en cours
 * @throws org.hibernate.HibernateException exception levée par Hibernate
 * lors de la récupération des données.
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException exception SQL 
 * levées lors de la récupération des données.
 */
@Override
public final void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object value, 
        final int index, final SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    if (value == null) {
        statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
    } else {
        String[] castObject = (String[]) value;
        Array array = session.connection().createArrayOf("text", castObject);
        statement.setArray(index, array);
    }
}

@Override
public final Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value;
}

@Override
public final boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public final Object assemble(final Serializable arg0, final Object arg1)
        throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public final Serializable disassemble(final Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public final boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
    if (x == y) {
        return true;
    } else if (x == null || y == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return x.equals(y);
    }
}

@Override
public final int hashCode(final Object x) throws HibernateException {
    return x.hashCode();
}

@Override
public final Object replace(
    final Object original,
    final Object target,
    final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return original;
}
```

}

And the last, but least (that's what I missed) : when I need to run SQL Native Query, I have to force the parameter type with the following syntax

```
String[] values = ...
Type arrayType = new CustomType(new ArrayUserType());
query.setParameter("value", values, arrayType);
```

Comment: What's the licence for this code? I want to use it in a GPL app.

Comment: Never mind, I'll probably reimplement it using CompositeUserType and ParameterizedType.

Comment: @z0r : I would say BSD ... ;-) No worries

Comment: @z0r: All code on stackoverflow is automatically CC BY-SA 3.0; see https://stackexchange.com/legal

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as "Damien C" but updated for Hibernate v5.4 (their solution doesn't work anymore with Hibernate v5.4):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.CustomType;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class ArrayUserType implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };


    public static Type createCustomType() {
        return new CustomType(new ArrayUserType());
    }

    /**
     * Return the SQL type codes for the columns mapped by this type. The
     * codes are defined on <tt>java.sql.Types</tt>.
     * 
     * @return int[] typecodes
     * @see java.sql.Types
     */
    public final int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    /**
     * The class returned by <tt>nullSafeGet()</tt>.
     * 
     * @return Class
     */
    public final Class<?> returnedClass() {
        return String[].class;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a JDBC resultset. Implementors
     * should handle possibility of null values.
     * 
     * @param resultSet A JDBC result set
     * @param names Column names
     * @param session  Session in progress
     * @param owner The containing entity 
     * @return Object
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException If the data can't be fetched
     */
    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws SQLException {
        if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }

        return resultSet.getArray(names[0]).getArray();
    }

    /**
     * Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement. Implementors
     * should handle possibility of null values. A multi-column type should be written
     * to parameters starting from <tt>index</tt>.
     * 
     * @param statement A JDBC prepared statement
     * @param value Object to write
     * @param index Statement parameter index
     * @param session Session in progress
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException If the data can't be fetched
     */
    @Override
    public final void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws SQLException {

        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        }
        else {
            String[] castObject = (String[]) value;
            Array array = session.connection().createArrayOf("text", castObject);
            statement.setArray(index, array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Object deepCopy(final Object value) {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object assemble(final Serializable arg0, final Object arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final Serializable disassemble(final Object arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return x.equals(y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode(final Object x) {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public final Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) {
        return original;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
String[] values = ...
query.setParameter("myArray", values, ArrayUserType.createCustomType());
```