# Join tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, join

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE tableOne (id int, name varchar(10), address varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE tableTwo (id int, info text, addresses varchar(20)[])
```

now I want to create a join as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableOne JOIN tableTwo ON address = ANY(addresses)
```

I tried to achieve this using Hibernate - class TableOne:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableOne")
class TableOne {
      private int id;
      private TableTwo tableTwo;
      private String address;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     public getId() { return id; }

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinFormula(value = "address = any(tableTwo.addresses)", 
                  referencedColumnName = "addresses")
     public TableTwo getTableTwo(){
        return tableTwo;
     }
     // Setters follow here

}
```

But Hibernate keeps generating queries with non-sense JOIN clauses, like:

```
... JOIN tableTwo ON _this.address = any(tableTwo.addresses) = tableTwo.addresses
```

How do I tell Hibernate using annotations to format my join query correctly? Unfortunately, our project must be restricted only to the Criteria API.

**EDIT:**

After suggestion from ashokhein in the comments below, I annotated the method `getTableTwo()` with just `@ManyToOne` - and now I would like to do the join using Criteria API, presumably with `createAlias(associationPath,alias,joinType,withClause)` method where `withClause` would be my `ON` clause in the join.

But Im not sure what to put as `associationPath` and `alias` parameters.

Any hints?

Comment: Don't do query creation in Entity class.It should not allowed to customize the query.

Comment: Do you mean rather creating a Native Query?

Comment: You can use NamedQuery,HSQL,Criteria

Comment: But how to annotate the `getTableTwo` method then?

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: Why to you use `@ManyToOne`? It looks like a `@OneToOne`. If it is realy a n-1, where is your `Collection` (`Set` or `List`)?

Comment: Another good example on how Hibernate gets really anoying when you need something that can be done with SQL and goes beyond the ORM... Thank you!  :- )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of time searching for the right answer, the only real solution that works for us is creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW TableA_view AS SELECT TableOne.*,TableTwo.id FROM TableA JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.address = ANY(TableTwo.addresses)
```

and mapping it to an entity `TableOne` instead of the original table.
This was the only solution for us besides, of course, using a named query, which was a no-go as we needed to stick to the Criteria API.

As @ericbn has mentioned in the comments this is really an example where ORM gets really annoying. I would never expect that custom join clause like this is not possible to do in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

To support PostgreSQL array you need a [custom Hibernate Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940642/hibernate-postgres-array-type). Having a dedicated user type will allow you to run native SQL queries to make use of the type:

```
String[] values = ...
Type arrayType = new CustomType(new ArrayUserType());
query.setParameter("value", values, arrayType);
```

[HQL supports ANY/SOME syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3319) but only for sub-queries. In your case you'll need a native query to use the PostgreSQL specific ANY clause against array values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Named Query.

```
  @NamedQuery(name="JOINQUERY", query="SELECT one FROM tableOne one JOIN tableTwo two ON one.address = :address" )
  @Entity
  class TableOne{......
```

Retrieving part is:

```
TypedQuery<TableOne> q = em.createNamedQuery("query", TableOne.class);
q.setParameter("address", "Mumbai"); 
for (TableOne t : q.getResultList())
  System.out.println(t.address);
```

You might need to do some permutations on the query

Answer (score -1):

`@JoinFormula` should contain SQL instead of HQL.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula.html

Comment: I think `address = any(tableTwo.addresses)` is "a valid SQL fragment" too.