# how to use postgresql array_agg with JPA+hibernate 3.6

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I make this request with no problem:

```
select ac.reg, param.alias, array_agg(numValue) 
from Sample   
group by ac.reg, param.alias  
order by ac.reg ASC
```

now, I want more than the mean value. how can I get all the values as an array? I use postgresql as DB, an I know there is a array_agg method that returns exaclty what I want. but such aggregation seems not to be implemented in hibernate.

```
select ac.reg, param.alias, array_agg(numValue) 
from Sample   
group by ac.reg, param.alias  
order by ac.reg ASC
```

raises the exception:

```
A java.lang.IllegalStateException has been caught, No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '(' +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'array_agg' {originalText=array_agg} \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList' \-[DOT] DotNode: 'sample0_.num_value' 
{propertyName=numValue,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=numValue,path={synthetic-alias}.numValue,tableAlias=sample0_,className=models.Sample,classAlias=null} +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}} \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'numValue' {originalText=numValue}
```

Comment: Arrays are introduced in JDBC4, but hibernate (and I think most jpa implementations) does not supprot them. In hibernate, you can use a [custom `UserType`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940642/hibernate-postgres-array-type) to use arrays in native queries...

Comment: ... But from your error message, it seems you try to run a jpql / hql. That wont work either: to use a function in hibernate, the underlying [dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect) must register it. Even  the `PostgreSQL94Dialect` does not register the `array_agg()` function.

Comment: @pozs : you mean that there is no solution to get something like 
`[{reg1, alias1, [1, 3, 29, 3]}, {reg1, alias2, [3, 9, 6, 0]},...]  ?`

Do you suggest I use native queries?

Comment: there is no easy solution. you could try with a custom usertype & a custom dialect, but I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: OK, then how can I get this structure? I have to get them without grouping and doing the job in JAVA?

Comment: "array_agg" is not a valid JPQL keyword, consequently your query is invalid.

Comment: @NeilStockton : that's clear. What workaround would you suggest?

Comment: If something is not valid with JPQL, then put it as a NATIVE query (i.e SQL). You then lose datastore independence, but that might not be a concern to you

Comment: make a database view with your query and then in jpa select from that view containing a field: (example for eclipselink 2.6): 

@Array(databaseType="TEXT[]")
 private List<String []>myArray;