# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : {1} with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I tried to launch a query using `CeateNativeQuery`:

```
String q = "select status.code as status, array_agg(reference.id) as ref  from reference_history
inner join reference on reference.id = reference_history.reference_id
inner join process_info on reference_history.process_info_id = process_info.id
inner join status  on process_info.status_id = status.id
where reference.code = 'ref123456'
and status.code in ('INPROGRESS', 'RESOLVED')
and start_date <= '2020-12-06'
and (end_date >= '2020-12-03' or end_date is null)
group by status";


List<Object[]> result = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
            .addScalar("ref", StandardBasicTypes.BIG_INTEGER)
            .getResultList();
```

I got this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : {1}
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:2910)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:2919)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNumeric(PgResultSet.java:2378)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:2332)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:390)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:394)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getBigDecimal(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I do not see column with `process` alias in your query.

Comment: @SternK sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: The PostgreSQL `ARRAY_AGG` function is an aggregate function that accepts a set of values and returns an array. So, it is not astonishing that you get this error when you try to convert it to the `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @SternK I just realized that but I didn't find how to map it from postgresql bigInt[] to Integer[] in java.

Comment: The PostgreSQL `BIGINT` data type is equivalent to a Java `Long` type, so a PostgreSQL array of those might be equivalent to a `Long[]` or a `List<Long>`. Did you try those?

Comment: addScalar() does not accept List<> or Arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as PostgreSQL `ARRAY_AGG` function returns array you ca not simply cast it to the `BigDecimal`. To do this you should write your own hibernate [custom basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) or you can use [hibernate types library](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types).

You can add for example this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

if you use hibernate 5.4, 5.3 or 5.2 and then write your query in the following way:

```java
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.LongArrayType;

List<Object[]> result = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
  .addScalar("status", StringType.INSTANCE)
  .addScalar("ref", LongArrayType.INSTANCE)
  .getResultList();
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940642/hibernate-postgres-array-type/) maybe will be useful if you decide to write your own hibernate type.