# How Do I Pass an Array of Strings Query String with the JdbcTemplate Query For Object Function?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, parameter-passing, jdbctemplate

I would like to pass an array of strings to a stored procedure with jdbcTemplate and am having trouble doing so. This is the query:

```
"SELECT * from stored_procedure(?::text[])"
```

This is how I am calling the stored procedure with the jdbcTemplate (where notes is a List):

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class, notes == null ? null : notes.toArray());
```

This is the error I get:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * from stored_procedure(?::text[])]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of [Ljava.lang.Object;. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I haven't found anything online for fixing this problem.

Comment: I don't recognize that notation. What database are you using?

Comment: I have answered this same kind of question in below link http://stackoverflow.com/a/39357138/2147560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) which supports named parameter binding (using `:foo` instead of `?`) and collection parameter expansion (expanding `:foo` to `?, ?, ?`). Then you can use:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM stored_procedure({:notes})", 
    Collections.singletonMap("notes", notes));
```

I don't think PostgreSQL JDBC driver supports array parameter types (i.e. you can not bind array to a single `?`).