# Insert values not working using Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am working in spring MVC with Hibernate as ORM..

In my module, I am calling a form action to store values into table. But the data is not inserted in that table. But I haven't got any errors in the log.

The code I tried with sessionFactory is,

```
        String querys = "insert into reconcile_process (process_type,fk_last_modified_by,fk_bank_stmt_id)"
                + " values (?,?,?)";
        Connection connections = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection();   
        PreparedStatement stmt = connections.prepareStatement(querys);      
        stmt.setString(1, "Auto");
        stmt.setInt(2, 1);
        stmt.setInt(3, 251);
        stmt.executeUpdate();;
        connections.close();
```

But in the same way, I can insert the values using JDBC driver as follows,

```
        private static final String DB_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxxx";
        private static final String DB_USER = "xxxxxx";
        private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "xxxxx";

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;     
        String querys = "INSERT INTO reconcile_process "
                + "(process_type,fk_last_modified_by,fk_bank_stmt_id) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?)";
        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(querys);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Type");
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, 45);   
            preparedStatement.setLong(3, 251);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }           

        private static Connection getDBConnection() {
            Connection dbConnection = null;
            try {
                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,
                        DB_PASSWORD);
                return dbConnection;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return dbConnection;
        }
```

Can anyone point me to where the problem is?

Comment: Where you  get problem, please show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in hibernate.cfg.xml file in default package

```
     <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

setting is exist. I think your operation is correct but because of Commit operation You didn't get correct result.

or because of `object of domain` class which you want to save pass to `session factory`

```
session.save(obj); 
txn.commit();
```

Comment: both technique works for annotation based hibernate.

Comment: When you perform reverse engineering from database then hibernate.cfg.xml fill will be generated and database username and password is stored there just add  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>  line to avoid repeation of txn.commit().

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property> is fixed this issue... Is there any other transactions would be affected to set this property? Coz, its setted as false..

Comment: Then after each transaction you perform commit operation as i explain in answer  SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
        new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    txn = session.beginTransaction();    txn.commit();

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode

Comment: perfect @SubodhJoshi thank you to explain in short words.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you are using Hibernate why not take its advantages

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
        new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    txn = session.beginTransaction();
    UrTableClass obj = new UrTableClass ();  
    obj.setDescription("Description");
    obj.setName("NAME");
    obj.setAge(28); 
    session.save(obj); 
    txn.commit();
```

Comment: I have a array type column in that table.. So I decided to go with native query using Hibernate.. Cant get way to use the array column in hibernate table...

Comment: Even then its easy but its all depend how you setup the things and how much time you have now.

Comment: I have enough time... I am confused to get the array in entity class

Comment: Also there is no clear references on how to insert arrays using Hibernate to postgres..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042181/how-can-i-set-a-string-parameter-to-a-native-query

Comment: In my case array is type of Long... I used that before and not able to insert because it accepts only string arrays...

Comment: http://javafreakers.com/how-to-store-array-in-database-in-a-single-column-using-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

For finding the root cause of the problem - I suggest starting the server in `debug` mode. And then using `F6` line by line debugging. This will help you track the values getting passed in the `objects`.
If you have been using hibernate,I strongly feel you are missing out some important configurations that are required in `hibernate.cfg.xml` to save in the database through `hibernate` .