# How to store an int[] or float[] in an SqLiteDataBase in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I have all these Strings like "TEXT", "INTEGER" and so on for a text or an integer.

Is there any method to add an integer array or a float array?

Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + ACCOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + TYPE + " INTEGER,"
            + AMOUNT + " INTEGER,"
            + YEAR + " INTEGER,"
            + MONTH + " INTEGER,"
            + DAY + " INTEGER,"
            + EXTRA + " TEXT"  + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: Maybe another table containing the array values and the primary key of that table would be foreign key in your existing table?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to store array. But you can do it other way.

*To Store : Convert array with comma separated string and store that.* (Read [Convert String[] to comma separated string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622974/convert-string-to-comma-separated-string-in-java))

*To Retrieve : Convert comma separated string into array.* (Read [How to split a comma-separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/splitting-a-comma-separated-string))

Answer (score 2):

While waiting somebody giving a better answer, you might want to try mine.

I usually save a **short** array (never tried for long arrays like 100+ items) just with `,`

For example :

```
1,3,5,6,7
```

And then i will use `split` method, and add those values to a `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 2):

The more SQL way would be to create a one-to-many relationship, and store the arrays as entries on the 'many' table.